QGIS extract minimum and maximum elevation in separate field
I am not an expert in QGIS with the field calculator. I have a point layer in which several points are identified with different ID. Some of the point have the same ID but different elevation information.
I would like to extract the minimum and maximum elevation separately (in two fields named Zmin and Zmax) for every ID. Is there a way to do it in the field calculator as I have a lot of points?

You can use aggregate functions minimum and maximum in calculator

Thank you that worked!

Open the Field Calculator
(Layer → Open Attribute Table → Click the calculator icon).
Create two new fields, one for Zmin (minimum elevation) and another for Zmax (maximum elevation).
For Zmin, use this expression:
minimum("elevation", group_by:="ID")
For Zmax, use this expression:
maximum("elevation", group_by:="ID")

